# Specific content assist for custom XML file types within an eclipse plug in

Tags: xml, eclipse, plugins

I have created a custom eclipse plugin for generating XML files (JDBC, CSV, LDAP).
Now I an trying to create specific content assistance for each file type. At the moment my plug in project provides me with the full range of suggestions no matter which file type is currently open. I want to know how to assign a certain content proposal class to one of my file types.

Below is my plugin.xml class if it is of any assistance.

```
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards">
      <category
            id="com.euclideanspace.spad.builder.category.wizards"
            name="IDome">
      </category>
      <wizard
            icon="icons/xml.png"
            category="com.euclideanspace.spad.builder.category.wizards"
            class="idome.xmlgenerator.wizards.BuilderDataModel"
            id="builder.wizard.new.custom"
            name="Model">

      </wizard>
      <category
            id="com.euclideanspace.spad.builder.category.wizards"
            name="IDome">
      </category>
      <wizard
            icon="icons/xml.png"
            category="com.euclideanspace.spad.builder.category.wizards"
            class="idome.xmlgenerator.wizards.BuilderJDBC"           
            id="builder.wizard.new.custom"
            name="JDBC">
      </wizard>
            <category
            id="com.euclideanspace.spad.builder.category.wizards"
            name="IDome">
      </category>
      <wizard
            icon="icons/xml.png"
            category="com.euclideanspace.spad.builder.category.wizards"
            class="idome.xmlgenerator.wizards.BuilderLDAP"          
            id="WorkingBackup.wizard2"
            name="LDAP">
      </wizard>
            <category
            id="com.euclideanspace.spad.builder.category.wizards"
            name="IDome">
      </category>
      <wizard
            icon="icons/xml.png"
            category="com.euclideanspace.spad.builder.category.wizards"
            class="idome.xmlgenerator.wizards.BuilderImport"
            id="WorkingBackup.wizard3"
            name="ImportCSV">
      </wizard>
            <category
            id="com.euclideanspace.spad.builder.category.wizards"
            name="IDome">
      </category>
      <wizard
            icon="icons/xml.png"
            category="com.euclideanspace.spad.builder.category.wizards"
            class="idome.xmlgenerator.wizards.BuilderExport"
            id="WorkingBackup.wizard4"
            name="ExportCSV">
      </wizard>
   </extension>


  <extension
     id="idome.xml.generator.contentassist"
     point="org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.completionProposal">         

    <proposalCategory 
           id="idome.xml.generator.contentassist"
           name="XML Content Assist">
    </proposalCategory>


 <proposalComputer
       activate="true"
       categoryId="idome.xml.generator.contentassist"
       class="idome.xmlgenerator.contentassist.ContentBlocks"
       id="idome.xml.generator.contentassist.contentblocks">            
        <contentType id="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml"/>            
    </proposalComputer>      

     <proposalComputer
       activate="true"
       categoryId="idome.xml.generator.contentassist"
       class="idome.xmlgenerator.contentassist.TaskCompletionProcessor"
       id="idome.xml.generator.contentassist.taskcompletionprocessor">          
        <contentType id="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml"/>            
    </proposalComputer>      

     <proposalComputer
       activate="true"
       categoryId="idome.xml.generator.contentassist"
       class="idome.xmlgenerator.contentassist.queryAssist"
       id="idome.xml.generator.contentassist.attributeassist.tableassist">          
        <contentType id="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml"/>            
    </proposalComputer>     

     <proposalComputer
       activate="true"
       categoryId="idome.xml.generator.contentassist"
       class="idome.xmlgenerator.contentassist.AttributesList"
       id="idome.xml.generator.contentassist.attributeslist">           
        <contentType id="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml"/>            
    </proposalComputer>    

        <proposalComputer
       activate="true"
       categoryId="idome.xml.generator.contentassist"
       class="idome.xmlgenerator.contentassist.AttributesAssist"
       id="idome.xml.generator.contentassist.attributeassist">          
        <contentType id="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml"/>            
    </proposalComputer>          

    </extension>
  <extension
        point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
     <editor
           class="idomexmlgenerator.editors.TaskTextEditor"
           contributorClass="org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.BasicTextEditorActionContributor"
           extensions="xml"
           icon="icons/sample.gif"
           id="idomexmlgenerator.editors.XMLEditor"
           name="Sample XML Editor">
     </editor>
  </extension>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to actually *separate* your file types so that you're not treating them all as generic XML files. Define some [content types](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/runtime_content_contributing.htm?cp=2_0_3_4_1). Once you have those defined, you'll be able to associate your proposal computers differently.